# Http Get Request From Angular to PHP Server issues

Tags: php, sql, angularjs

How to create the GET request with parameter and pass the parameter to PHP page and using that value to create a dynamic SELECT where query and populate the response in angular UI ? Let you explain the code and other details briefly.

**sample.js**

```
var link = 'http://www.testhostfile.com/GetData.php';

$http({
url: link,
method: "GET",
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
data: $scope.inmateData.IMID

}).then(function (res){
alert('Success');
console.log(res);
});
```

**GetData.php**

```
<?php

$db_name  = 'testDb';
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'testName';
$password = 'password';
$usertable = "InMateMaster";    

$fileData = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($fileData);

if (isset($request)) {

$imID = $request->IMID;

echo($imID);
}

$db = new mysqli("localhost",$username,$password,$db_name);

if($db->connect_errno > 0) {
die('Unable to connect to database[' .$db->connect_error. ']');
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM InMateMaster WHERE IMID = 'KAS9791257393'";


if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
die('There was an error running the query [' .$db->error. ']');
}

$arr = array();
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$item = array();
$item['IMName'] = $row['IMName'];
$item['IMMobile'] = $row['IMMobile'];
$item['IMFatherName'] = $row['IMFatherName'];
$arr[] = $item;
}
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

Now How to assign the dynamic value which i have passed from GET request parameter to here like below:

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM InMateMaster WHERE IMID = 'here i need to set'";

As per below query, I received the response like in the below snap.

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM InMateMaster WHERE IMID = 'KAS9791257393'";

**Response :**

[image: Output]

> 1.So, How can I using select query dynamically - in the sense How can I pass one value from GET request and in that value how to query using SELECT and WHERE and how to populate the result in angular.
>
> 2.As per below response in the snap. How can I get those values in angular any idea ?

[{"IMName":"Venu M","IMMobile":"9791257393","IMFatherName":"Murugan N"}]

Let me know, If you need anymore clarifications in this.

Comment: It's a GET request, just like any other. If you want to pass data, you do it in the query string: `http://example.com/script.php?foo=bar`, which produces `$_GET['foo'] = 'bar'` on the server. GET requests do **NOT** have an http "body", so reading from php://input is useless. that will never have anything available.

Comment: @Marc - So it's not possible to do like POST - that we send parameter and get that parameter in PHP and using that value I can not able to query ? But i want dynamic query like while sending GET request i need send the Id of the user in that I want to query like SELECT *from Inmate where id = 'received parameter here' ?

Comment: if you have only `http://example.com/script.php?{"foo":"bar"}`, then there's NOTHING for php to create a key=value pair in $_GET from. You'd have to read `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING']` or whatever.

Comment: @Marc Pls find my updated cmts above.

Comment: Thanks much @Marc - pls find my below workouts and suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

I used below way to achieve the data from angular to PHP via Get request as per Mr.Marc suggestion it's working well.

> sample.js

```
$http.get('http://www.hostelkasthuri.com/GetInmate.php?'+$scope.inmateData.IMID
                      ).success(function(response) {
                              alert("SUCCESS!");
                              console.log(response.IMName);
                              })
                     .error(function(data) {
                            alert("ERROR");
                            alert(data);
                            });
```

> sample.php

```
$imID= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
echo "The query string is: " . $imID;
```

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM InMateMaster WHERE IMID = '$imID'";

My question here is - As per above workout Now can able to get the response from PHP using dynamic query.

Response :

> {"IMName":"Suthan M","IMMobile":"9659057393","IMFatherName":"Murugan N"}

Now, How can I retrieve above format of response into angular js any idea ?

My working code is here but how to get each value in angular response block ?

```
$http.get('http://www.hostelkasthuri.com/GetInmate.php?'+$scope.inmateData.IMID
                  ).success(function(response) {
                          alert("SUCCESS!");
                          console.log(response.IMName);
                          })
                 .error(function(data) {
                        alert("ERROR");
                        alert(data);
                        });
```

response.IMName - getting null why ?